# Winforms ListViewItems does not shows

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Why after invoking `SetListView(ListView listView)` in `Form1` ListViewItems does not shows in ListView?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IView
    {
        Presenter presenter;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            presenter = new Presenter(this, new Model());
        }

        public void SwitchToControl(UserControl userControl)
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl);
        }
        public void SetListView(ListView listView)
        {
            this.listView1 = listView;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            presenter.SwitchToFirst();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            presenter.SwitchToSecond();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            presenter.SetListView();
        }

    }
    interface IView
    {
        void SwitchToControl(UserControl userControl);
        void SetListView(ListView listView);
    }
    class Presenter
    {
        private readonly IView view;
        private readonly IModel model;

        public Presenter(IView view, IModel model)
        {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        public void SwitchToFirst()
        {
            var control = new UserControl1();
            view.SwitchToControl(control);
        }

        public void SwitchToSecond()
        {
            var control = new UserControl2();
            view.SwitchToControl(control);
        }

        public void SetListView()
        {
            ListView listView = new ListView();
            listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Text = "First" });
            listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Text = "Second" });
            listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Text = "Third" });
            listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Text = "Fourth" });
            view.SetListView(listView);
        }
    }
    interface IModel
    {

    }
    class Model : IModel
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You must add your listView to Controls from Form1.

Comment: @x..., this.listView1 = listView; I thought that it should work.

Comment: No it wont work. It just cause `listView1` point to a new in-memory `ListView` which is not visible on your form and is completely different than the one you see on the form. The one you see on the form is created in `InitializeComponent` and added to `Controls`  collection of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listView1` is only a variable pointing to the `ListView` control which you created and added to form in `InitializeComponent`. If you assign a new `ListView` to the variable, it doesn't have any impact on the `ListView` control which is in the `Controls` collection of the form.

After assigning the new instance to the variable, the `ListView` which you see on the form is the original one which is in `Controls` collection, but the `listView1` variable points to a different instance which you can not see and it's only in memory, and any changes on `listView1` will not be visible for you.

If you want to provide new items for the existing `ListView`, just pass new items to the form and after clearing previous items, add those new items.